# tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath: on iOS 3.x gets called over and over again when moving rows

Tags: iphone, uitableview, iphone-sdk-3.0

As the topic says, this method gets called over and over again when I move rows and crashes.
It works fine on iOS 4.x

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
  NSUInteger fromRow = [fromIndexPath row];
  NSUInteger toRow = [toIndexPath row];
  id object = [[array objectAtIndex:fromRow] retain];
  [array removeObjectAtIndex:fromRow];
  [array insertObject:object atIndex:toRow];
  [object release];
  [self reloadTableView];
}

-(void)reloadTableView{
 [myTableView reloadData];
}
```

I don't have any idea why. Please help.

Comment: I edited the post. In the future, use capitalization to start your sentences. It makes the post easier to read for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need:

```
[self reloadTableView];
```

...or:

```
[myTableView reloadData];
```

If you have to reload, do this:

```
[myTableView performSelector:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
```

Comment: I actually do cause I do have a label in my UITableViewCell that has to be updated.

Comment: then use [myTableView performSelector:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];

Comment: this did the trick for me! thanks a lot! post it as a new answer so I can mark it as the right answer! thanks again!